# Does maximizing log likelihood lead to maximizing mutual information?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, mutual-information

In supervised learning, we usually maximize log-likelihood, for example, by minimizing cross-entropy loss. Let's say we have data $X$ and their respective labels $Y$. We train a model to output a certain variable ($Z$) so that $p_{model} (y|x;\theta)$ obtained from $Z$, through softmax for example, is maximized. Then can we safely say that maximizing log-likelihood leads to maximization $I(Y;Z)$ during supervised learning?

I have read a [paper about cross-entropy loss](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.08983.pdf) which insists that minimizing cross-entropy loss leads to maximization of mutual information. Since cross-entropy loss is negative log-likelihood, perhaps a claim that maximizing ML leads to maximizing MI does not seem too ridiculous? I was not able to find a reference that explicitly says so...